# Crontab - trouble importing Python modules

Tags: python, python-requests, cron

I need to make a get request to a website every X minutes, and I can't get it working in crontab. I've tried:

- Writing a shell script containing the python path (PYTHONPATH=/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python) and the path to the python file
- Specifying the python path directly in cron, attempted with both the python file and the shell file
- Adding the pythonpath as a shebang to the top of my python script and running that

All attempts at running the python or shell file have contained the full pathway to the file. The pythonpath is copied from $ which python.

Nothing I've tried has worked and they all fail at the same point, importing the requests module. I have no idea what I'm missing.

The only thing I can see is that requests is install in anaconda3/lib whereas the pythonpath leads to anaconda3/bin, but I'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: maybe first create script which display (or better save in file) all information about running Python - and run it in `cron`. This way you will know what Python version it is using and you will know where you have to install `requests`  module. System may have many Pythons installed and it may use Python which doesn't have `requests` installed. And then you will have to install `requests` in correct Python. And better install it as global module, not local one because `cron` can run script with different settings/privileges.